# Change style on disabled date picker in Angular Material Design

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I'm making an Angular Material website. It contains a date picker. The date picker has the popup enabled but input disabled. This results in a style with a dotted line under the input element. How do i change the styling to make the dotted line solid?

The documentation has an example of the date picker with disabled input right here: https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/examples See the "Disabled datepicker"part.

Comment: You can view the CSS in the source code.

Comment: I tried that, but I just couldn't find that part of the CSS that controls the styling of that line.

Comment: Can you try placing a `disabled` attribute on the `input`?

Comment: facing the same issue, still not clear on what is causing this but class mat-input-underline mat-form-field-underline is enabling display of solid line.

Answer (score 3):

On input tag use readonly attribute.